# .NET Double.TryParse(num, format, cultureinfo, out) Error

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, internationalization, double

**Background:** I recently had the pleasure of writing code that needed to reliably convert strings to doubles internationally. This functionality also had to be distributed. i.e. the string was stored in the database and needed to be converted to a number on numerous agents running across various locales. For constraint reasons changing the database schema was out of the question and I had to make this work in a legacy code base with an easy upgrade path and without breaking the existing functionality.

I was able to solve this by normalizing the stored string to an invariant format and adding a flag to the encoding to indicate whether the value was normalized and should take the new path or non-normalized (sp?) and take the legacy path.

I forgot mention that the original value is entered by an end user and has to be in the range of acceptable formats. Meaning the stored value may or may not have number grouping specifiers. Obviously this is dangerous, it's currently only for beta, and properly internationalizing the UI is slated to happen soon for a proper release.

That said I figured it was reasonable that my conversion code should be able to handle number grouping characters even though the final normalized form won't include them. Double.TryParse() and Double.ToString() provided with a proper culture format should have no problem handling this and the conversion code may be reused for other reasons (yay legacy code!).

**The .NET error** So I figure it would be a good idea to write some unit tests around the internationalized string to double conversion code.

I write two main tests (kind of psuedo code).

Test1:

```
Double testValue = 15000.05
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures) 
{
    string testString = testValue.ToString(ci);
    Assert.AreEqual(testValue, Convert(testString, ci));
}
```

Test2:

```
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures) 
{
    string testString = testValue.ToString("N2", ci);
    Assert.AreEqual(testValue, Convert(testString, ci));
}
```

Relevant conversion code (almost line for line):

```
If Not Double.TryParse(numIn, Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, cultureInfo, numOut) Then Return False
```

For tests the exact method of gathering all the culture codes may be different, the method signature of Convert is different, and the surrounding code and assert is slightly different.
The relevant part is the .ToString(ci) and the .ToString("N2", ci).
For en-US these to version will generate "15000.05" and "15,000.05" respectively.
Also, this code is run under .NET versions 2.0 - 4.5.2 and we run the tests under the various relevant version. It behaves the same across the board (*may need to double check this but it's definitely the behavior in .NET 4.5.2)

Test1 passes!

Test2 fails on these 5 culture codes:

- prs
- prs-AF
- tzm
- tzm-Latn
- tzm-Latn-DZ

We're currently ignoring these failures as not supported and tracking if any new ones we care about show up.

**Diagnosis**
After digging around and experimenting some we trace the issue down to the number grouping specifier. i.e. the thousandths place separator.
Changing Double.TryParse() to

```
numOut = Double.Parse(numIn, ci)
```

Works. So the issue is specifically with Double.TryParse() and probably having to do with the NumberStyle.Any specifier. Or'ing it with the hex specifier doesn't work either.

So we have a situation in .NET where you can convert a double to a string using a specific IFormatProvider, then attempt to convert it back to a double using that same IFormatProvider, and it will fail.

**Question:** Can anyone explain why this occurs?

**Running Theories:** My two current ideas are a character encoding bug with the number grouping character or the actual double representation under the hood for those specific cultures is different (similar to how double x = 0.3 is really 0.299... in .NET).

**Disclaimer:** I switch between VB.NET and C# so please excuse any syntactical mix ups. Also, I'm aware that the test doesn't properly account for "odd" number groupings like in Hindi where 1,015,000 is written 10,15,000.

Comment: Haven't been able to do further diagnosis yet but I just submitted an issue on the dotnet github repo: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/12340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tarekgh posted an answer on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/12340). The following is what he wrote:

"The problem here is the failing cultures for you have the following:

Decimal separator is ","
Group Separator is "."
Currency Decimal separator is "."
Currency Group Separator is ","
Notice that the decimal separators is same as the currency group separator. Also the group separator is same as the currency decimal separator.

Now when you format the number with such culture, you'll get the string "15.000,05". when you are trying to parse it back you are passing NumberStyles.Any which means the string can be a currency number or it can be decimal number. This confuse the parser when trying to parse the character "." as it can be treated as currency decimal separator or it can be treated as group separator. The parser decide to treat it as currency decimal separator. Then the parser will continue till hitting "," and again will treat this as currency group separator. because the group separator cannot come after the decimal separator, the parser will fail to parse the string and will return false from TryParse (or throw exception from Parse).

The way to fix this, remove the currency parsing from passed NumberStyles. i.e.

```
        Double.TryParse(numString, NumberStyles.Any & (~NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol), ci, out numParsed);
```

I am going to close the issue but feel free to respond back with any more questions if you have any."